# In OS X who owns the model, NSDocument or NSViewController

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nsviewcontroller

Working in iOS I've never dealt with OS X and NSDocument based apps. Where should the model reference live, inside the NSDocument or the representedObject in the NSWindow's content NSViewController? Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be stored in the NSDocument object as stated by the Apple documentation in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Designing/Designing.html). In particular, check Figure 1-1. Further below, on the same page, Apple states that a **data model corresponds to a document type**, so if you have different models you should use different document types that should be stored in NSDocument objects.